# How to match all words after a specific expressions with regex?

Tags: swift, regex

How to match all words (separated by a comma) after a specific expressions with regex?

My code below matches the first word after a specific expressions:

```
\b(?:let|var)\s+(\w+)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, you can use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\b(?:var|let)\s+)(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9rp8Ty/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\b(?:var|let)\s+)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*` - end of the previous match and then a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `|` - or
  - `\b(?:var|let)\s+` - a word boundary, `var` or `let` and then one or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars.

See the Swift demo:

```swift
import Foundation

let string = "let constant1, constant2, constant3: String"
extension String {
    func groups(for regexPattern: String) -> [[String]] {
    do {
        let text = self
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexPattern)
        let matches = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return matches.map { match in
            return (1..<match.numberOfRanges).map {
                let rangeBounds = match.range(at: $0)
                guard let range = Range(rangeBounds, in: text) else {
                    return ""
                }
                return String(text[range])
            }
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
}
let result = string.groups(for: #"(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\b(?:var|let)\s+)(\w+)"#).flatMap { $0 }
print(result)
```

Output:

```
["constant1", "constant2", "constant3"]
```

Answer (score 3):

For the example data (and if a lookbehind is supported), you might try one of these patterns.

But if you want to parse Javascript, it would be a better option to use a Javascript parser as using a regex is error prone.

```
(?<=\b(?:var|let)\s+(?:\w+,\s*)*)\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AtJ59X/1)

Or

```
(?<=\b(?:var|let)\s+(?:\w+(?::[^:,]*)?,\s*)*)\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RDcoUI/1)

Comment: thanks, seems it is not supported with Swift regex flavor or PHP, is there another way?

Comment: @HassanTaleb like this? `(?:\b(?:var|let)\s+|\G(?!^)(?::\s*\w+)?,\s*)\K\w+` see https://regex101.com/r/05p6V8/1

Comment: Thanls! works in php but in Swift no, I think Swift is like python in regex?