# How to match all func parameters in regex with the func name

Tags: swift, regex

My code below matches all func parameters without the func name:

```
(?<=\(|\,)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?=\:|\s*)
```

How can I add a condition to match the func name and its parameters only if there is a "func" keyword?
[image]

**Edited:**
Working with the code written by @tukan:

```
((?<=func\s)\w+)|(\w+(?=:))
```

text code to test:

```
func foo(a: Int, b: String = "myStr", c: Double)

func foo(a s1: Int, b s2: String = "myStr", c: Double = 1.0)

func     foo(a: Int, b: String, c: Double = 3343)

func foo()
```

[image]

Comment: You need the same approach as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72680528/3832970). BTW, `(?=\:|\s*)` is redundant, it allows an empty string, so there is no restriction. Try `(?:\G(?!\A)\s*[(,:]\s*|\bfunc\s+)(\w+)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2hyzlT/1).

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question to make it more clear, please take a look. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of 2 capture groups and the `\G` anchor

```
 (?:\b(func)\s+\w+\(|\G(?!^)(?::\s*\w+)?,\s*)(\w+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\b(func)\s+\w+\(` Capture `func` in **group 1**
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, but not at the start of the string (as `\G` can match at both positions)
  - `(?::\s*\w+)?,\s*` Optionally match a colon, optional spaces, then a comma and optional spaces
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in **group 2**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IYYC5Q/1)

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question to make it more clear, please take a look.

Comment: @HassanTaleb The pattern by tukan matches in this example, but note that the alternation `|` in this case is not bounded to the func, so it will match any wordchars direcly followed by `:`  Is the new image in your question actually a new question?

Comment: It is the same question, but with all possibilities for a "func" (I think)

Comment: @HassanTaleb but actually you want to parse a programming language with a regex right? In that case it would be better to consider using a dedicated parser.

Comment: I modified your code to this : ```(?:\b(func)\s+\w+\(|\G(?!^)(?:\s*\w*\s*:\s*\w+)?\s*,\s*)(\w+)``` the only problem is when there is a default value for the parameter, like this example: ```func foo(a b: Int, c: String = "myStr", d: Int)``` the matching stop at c , is there a solution for that?